# IE box-shadow CSS not working

Tags: internet-explorer, css

On my website `[removed]` I have box-shadow applied to the top menu.
Of course, I want this to show on IE too.

So I've applied this code for IE8 and lower:

```
zoom:1; /* This enables hasLayout, which is required for older IE browsers */
/* For IE 5.5 – 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=140, Color=’#444444’);
/* For IE 8 */
-ms-filter: “progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=140, Color=’#444444’)”;
```

But as you can see on the website, that doesn't work.
What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: are **’** supposed to be **'**?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't be of any assistance, but that `box-shadow` under the carousel is great! How did you do it?

Comment: When I check your website I get box shadows showing in IE8. The :hover doesn't work, but the shadow does for me.

Comment: @Blender Thanks. Shame it's an image really. Now I feel like a real moron for not spotting that when I had Firebug open!

Comment: @JamWaffles, I'm using the Karma wordpress theme. It's really nice.

Comment: @Blender, could you please edit your post please? I don't want this URL to be indexed, thanks :)

Comment: @mwan, that's really strange. When I look at it on IE8 I don't see any shadows.

Comment: @priktop: Sorry, can't edit now. Had to delete...

Comment: @priktop: Okay, that's strange. I'm not sure whether you've changed something in the last 10 mins but I just went back into IE8 to take a screenshot, and I no longer see the boxes or the shadows - but they were 100% DEFINITELY there before, I had a Chrome and IE8 window side-by-side comparing them... Weird...

Answer (score 3):

Your quotes are curly quotes. Try this instead:

```
zoom:1; /* This enables hasLayout, which is required for older IE browsers */
/* For IE 5.5 – 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=140, Color='#444444');
/* For IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=140, Color='#444444')";
```

---

I've heard good reviews about this JavaScript library: [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/).

It seems to work with IE6-9, and all you have to do is add this line of CSS to your element:

```
behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
```

The script will read the CSS3 properties and render them accordingly.

Comment: Was hoping that this'd be the answer. I've applied it, but no luck :(

Comment: I've tried PIE before, and now again to test my luck, but no results :(

Comment: It should work. Remove those CSS properties up there, upload PIE to the root directory of your site, and it should work perfectly. What exactly isn't working with it?

Comment: I don't know :) Removed all the above, included PIE with the correct path, but no results... I don't get it either.

Comment: I hate you, IE, with a vengeance. I'm not sure what to do, then, as that's all that I would try myself ;(

Answer (score 1):

You don't need quotes on the `color` property (curly or otherwise).  Take those off and I think you should be okay.  So

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, 
    Direction=140, Color=#444444);
```

Etc.

Check out the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086(v=vs.85).aspx

**EDIT**

You also might want to try the `-ms-filter` extension

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(trength=5, 
        Direction=140, Color=#444444, positive=true)";
```

Comment: I've got it working now in all IE versions, except IE8. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, the same thing i am trying but its giving me only right side shadow but i want to have left and right side shadow. Can anybody suggest how to do this??    What i am trying to do is as follows:              filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=360, Color=#999999,positive=true); MIN-HEIGHT: 600px; WIDTH: 592px; BACKGROUND: #ffffff; FLOAT: left; MARGIN-LEFT: 11px; box-shadow: #999 0px 13px 18px; -moz-box-shadow: #999 0px 13px 18px; -webkit-box-shadow: #999 0px 13px 18px

Comment: filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=-115, Color=#999999,positive=true); Which direction to be set for right and left shadow????

Comment: It is supposed to be sorted **top/right/bottom/left**. I found that while using the **filter** tag, I had to put all four of them for the shadow to work. Let's say you want only left and right shadows, I had to put 

`-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=0, Direction=0, Color='#000000')", "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=90, Color='#000000')", "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=0, Direction=0, Color='#000000')", "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=270, Color='#000000')";` 
for it to work.